# Why does web app deployed via ECS experience blocking but does not when deployed via EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, playframework, amazon-ecs

I have a scala play framework-based web app. I have an ECS deployment that experiences blocking with certain web requests while an EC2-based deployment does not.  I am wondering if there are any other architectural or configuration differences between ECS and EC2 that I need to adjust.

Here are some points on the two deployments:

- Every controller endpoint should be async out of the box with this web framework.
- I deploy via a docker container.
- The web app has a spark session set up that communicates with a remote server. I only experience blocking of requests when the remote cluster is being hit for the first time or is getting set up. on ECS deployment
- ECS deployment is assigned 16vCPU and 32GiB. EC2 server is a `c5d.4xlarge` that has 32GiB and 16vCPUs.
- Both have application load balancers for routing traffic

I tried increasing some of the Ulimit settings in the ECS deployment, nofile and nproc, but that did not seem to make a difference. I tried decreasing the number of threads assigned to the spark session by changing the master conf setting from `local[*]` to `local[2]`. I expected no blocking to occur but it still did.